# Extract string before "............"

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract information before many dots.

For example if my string is : ""Profile Tests .........................................". All I want is to extract "Profile Tests".

My actual code is :

```
s1 = "Profile Tests ........................................."
s1.partition('.')[0]
```

It's working because I'm getting : "Profile Tests" but when I try with another string, for example:

```
s1 = "Issuer may be subject to a 30 per cent."
s1.partition('.')[0]
```

I'm getting "Issuer may be subject to a 30 per cent". But I don't want to extract if I have only one dot.

How would I extract information only if I have many '.' in my string ?

Comment: split the string on `..` and then just take the first part of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to match a string with 3 or more dots at the end of it.
You match anything you want in the character class ( [ ] ) and specify that it must be followed by 3 or more dots.

Regex: `([\w ]+)\.{3,}$`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/MbSJWo/2

Answer (score 0):

Set the separator in the partition function to the number of points you want to find. So for example, if you want 3 points to extract the previous string you should use:

```
s1.partition('...')[0]
```

Then, you should take into account that if the string '...' is not in s1 you should return null (or whatever you want), so the final code would be:

```
if s1.partition('...')[0] is s1:
    result = null
else:
    result = s1.partition('...')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

l = 'Issuer may be subject to a 30 per cent.'

**Use below commmand**
l.replace('.', '') if l.count('.') > 1 else l

Answer (score -1):

You can locate the first '.' with the find method of the str type. Then you can use the slice operator to get the substring before the '.' character.

```
st = 'Profile Tests .........................................'
loc = st.find('.')
st = st[:loc]
```

Comment: It's working for "Profile Tests" but it's also extracting "Issuer may be subject to a 30 per cent" from the second string.